# Reading tableNames from spm in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dataadapter

Is there a way I can read the table names which are returning me data from spm? I'm trying to  read the tableNames used in the return statement of spm executed to fill my dataset.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: When saying 'spm' are you mean a Stored procedure?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801799/how-to-return-table-name-from-stored-procedure-in-dataset

Comment: Am I missing something? How does "spm" translate to stored procedure?

Comment: @ean5533 It's a "stored procedure, man!"

Comment: Create Output Param in SP, fill the table name in that parameter.