# How to present the data from multiple DataTables in a series of stacked data grids?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have an undefined amount of `DataTables`. I get them from my `DataBase`, each `DataTable` stands for one Table in my `DataBase`, I dont use all Tables of the `DataBase` just the few I need (these were selectet earlier in the code) and not all columns (same like the tables).

Now my *problem*: I want to show them in a `DataGrid` one below the other with breaks between them for the tablename.

This is how i get my DataTables:

```
List<DBTable> selectedTbl = DBObject.SingDBObj.GetSelectedTables();

foreach (DBTable tbl in selectedTbl)
{
    string cols = tbl.GetSelectedColumnNames();

    string query = @"SELECT " + cols + " FROM [" + DBObject.SingDBObj.DataSource + "].[" + DBObject.SingDBObj.Database + "].[" + tbl.Schema + "].[" + tbl.Name + "];";
    DataTable DTShow = DBObject.SingDBObj.ExecuteQuery(query);
}

dataGridShowColmns.DataContext = ??;
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Surely you know what the names of the tables are?

Comment: I have the diffrent DataTables and I know the names but i have no clou how to bring them together like I describe it.

Comment: Similar to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14358983/1073107

Answer (score 1):

You maybe mean something like:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// dataset is here just initialized for demonstration, you would first
// get the tables from database and populate dataset

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[i];

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL name to a dataset cannot be assigned, only way you can do it in c#/VB. like

```
Dataset.Table[0].Name = "MyTable";
```